# What do the abbreviations "etc" and "usr" mean?

Tags: filesystem

I can relate to acronyms and abbreviations much more readily when I actually know how they were derived.

It is **oftn pssble to wrk out wht an abrvtion means** if you know the the root words behind it... but unfortunately `etc` is a standard abbreviation for "**et-cetera**"... and for `usr` I think of **"user**"... but I can't see any correlation.

Most of the terse names in Linux actually make sense when I finally work out the **expanded** original normal words behind them..

Are the origins of these abbreviations lost in the mists of time, or are they "obvious" to all but me?

This question was prompted by a comment I read yesterday, where someone described these things as Linux **incantations** ... I sympathize with him :)...

Comment: Here's a relevant Server Fault question with plenty of interesting info: http://serverfault.com/questions/137605/what-do-these-abbreviations-stand-for

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you suspected, `/etc` is from etcetera, unhelpfully named for "where everything else goes", and `/usr` was for "user applications". A lot of the detail on the history of the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) is documented on Wikipedia.

Comment: I'll check your link... but I've also heard that /etc meant **Editable Text Configuration**, and /usr means **U(forget) System Resources(?)**...  It isn't anything critical, but I'd just like to know the **original** wording, way back when....

Comment: Editable Text Configuration seems to be a "backronym" and not the true origin.

Comment: Okay... If the origina Bell-Labs comments says "etc" means et-cetera... I'm happy with that .... and Okay again for /usr meaning "(multi-)user utilities and applications" ...  Thanks...  I missed the forest for the trees...

Answer (score 13):

I heard that /usr was for **U**nix **S**ystem **R**esources.

Comment: I don't think is was, but it is now!

Comment: Thanks... Ah, "Unix"; that's the one I had heard of and couldn't quite recall... I certainly now have meaningful phrases to associate with abbreviations :) ...

Comment: +1 That indeed seems to be the case: http://serverfault.com/questions/137605/what-do-these-abbreviations-stand-for/137608#137608

Answer (score 8):

`/etc` is an abbreviation for etcetera, as I'm sure you guessed... It's the directory which stores all of your configuration files. `/usr`, as you guessed, is the directory where "user" files reside; it contains all of the items that are not part of the system itself such as user programs and data. System programs are stored in `/bin`, user programs in `/usr/bin`, or, in Ubuntu, in `/usr/share/`. [TuxFiles](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxdir.html) has a good description of the Linux directory structure.

Comment: Dang, ninja'd! All yours, Kees.

Comment: The directory  isn't "et-ceteras" in nature .. etc-cetera means "and sundries"... As far as I can see, there is anything but sundries in "/etc" ...  I have heard (somewhere) that it means **"Editable Text Configuration"**.. This makes sense to me, but I's still kike to know it that was the **original meaning**... (maybe Linus Torvals or Richard Stallman would know **for certain** :)

Comment: I can't see why either of those two people would know fred. I think the terms goes way back to Unix/POSIX and isn't a Linux or Gnu term.

Comment: They probably would, but the directory structure is actually a holdover from UNIX. We've developed in our methods of storing things; for example, /home/ isn't standard in UNIX or BSD directory structures, it's a new-ish development that is associated primarily with Linux. /usr/home is generally more common for old-style systems. It may have been that in the past /etc/ _was_ used more for bits and pieces, but we've developed it to a more dedicated area for conf files. http://ask.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=07/03/03/028258 <- This slashdot thread has a post indicating this concept.

Comment: Thanks.. good info... I'll now think of /etc as "et-cetera"* with a lot of *"Editable Text Configs"* in it.... and /usr as **"User** *system resources"*, because that's what it seems to hold.. I'll work with that mental image, unless someone points out that I'm off the track

Comment: @Martin: a good point.. thanks for the perspective.

Answer (score 2):

The abbrevation "usr" of "/usr" does **not** mean user.
That was only until 10 years ago or so. Since around 2000 it's now the abbrevation for "Unix System Resources".