# Weird folder names in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: filesystem

I have a few questions. Some things are bothering me, and maybe if I can understand why they are a certain way, I can rest my mind a bit.

In Windows, about 95% of folder and file names make sense. They clearly describe their purpose.

On linux, the official User Manual, states the following:

1. > `/bin` and `/sbin`: Stores many **essential** system applications
2. > `/etc`: Stores **System**-wide **configuration** files.

My question is, Why are folder names so <strike>silly</strike> / <strike>stupid</strike> / <strike>weird</strike> / unrelated to their purpose?

Why would "essential **system** applications" be placed in a folder named after a thing that is used to hold unwanted things? (bin)

Why would "system-wide configuration files" be stored in a folder called "etc"?

Comment: "bin", probably standing for binary, is a file type. However I prefer this kind of names to prevent ordinary people from breaking their system -- when they don't understand they'll give up.

Comment: They are probably such so that **users may have to type less**. I would personally prefer to type `/sbin` rather than `/system\ binary`(although there is auto-completion in BASH, but still)

Comment: How does 'system32' folder in windows make sense to you??? And how does the name 'windows' itself make sense anyways?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout/138551#138551

Comment: Related: `$ man hier`

Comment: Also, on 64-bit windows systems, the 64-bit binaries are in "System32" and the 32-bit binaries are in "SysWoW64". Wish I was making this up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. `/bin` stands for **binaries**, `/sbin` stands for **system binaries**
2. `etc` stands for **etcetera** (this directory historically held everything that did not belong elsewhere)

You  can read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11286/what-do-the-abbreviations-etc-and-usr-mean) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/137605/what-do-these-abbreviations-stand-for); and on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Answer (score 5):

Most of the directory names are not unrelated, but simply too short to be comprehensible without further knowledge. But this is not just a Linux issue. Other Unix-like systems as Apple's OS X for example or Solaris use the same weird names. And since you mentioned Windows... You just have to dig deeper. For example the hosts file for windows has this weird path:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

There you have your unrelated "etc" again ;-)

For a quick overview over the role of the different Linux directory names take a look to this Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: That /etc IS related to OUR /etc: they stem from the same origin ;)

Answer (score 3):

`bin` first of all means binary, and despite it is also the different word *bin* nobody associated it to any *bin* but **binary**. It was always clean in the context of Unix. Also they were needed to use really shorts, preferably three-lettered words, when they were always typing a lot. As a compliance it is still there.